# Differences between least-squares estimate and weighted least-squares estimate when I focus on only one coefficient in a multiple linear regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, estimation, least-squares, weighted-regression

Suppose we have $n$ samples from the following linear model:
$$y=x_1 \beta_1+x_2 \beta_2 + e,$$
where $e_i$  i.i.d. comes from $N(0,\sigma^2)$; $x_1$, $x_2$ are centralized with mean $0$.

I am **only interested in $\beta_1$**.

1. While, we know that the least squares estimate $\widehat{\beta}_1^{(1)} =(x_1^\prime x_1)^{-1} x_1^\prime y$ is poor, because it doesn't consider the effect of $x_2$ on $y$ and could lead to large estimation variance.
2. Let $x = (x_1, x_2)\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 2}$.
   We have the least-squares estimate of $(\beta_1, \beta_2)^\prime$,
   \begin{align}
   (\widehat{\beta}_1^{(2)} , \widehat{\beta}_2^{(2)})^\prime
   & = (x^\prime x)^{-1} x^\prime y.
   \end{align}
3. Denote by $P_M$ the projection matrix corresponding to a design matrix $M$.
   Denote by $I_n$ the identity matrix of order $n$.
   Let
   \begin{align}
   \widehat{\beta}_1^{(3)} 
   & = \{x_1^\prime [I_n − x_2 (x_2^\prime x_2 ^{−1}) x_2^\prime ] x_1 \}^{−1} x_1^\prime [I_n−x_2 (x_2^\prime x_2 )^{−1} x_2^\prime ] y \\
   & = [x_1^\prime (I_n − P_{x_2} ) x_1 ]^{−1} x_1^\prime (I_n−P_{x_2} ) y.
   \end{align}

My **questions** are:

1. Is $\widehat{\beta}_1^{(3)}$ also the least-squares estimate of $\beta_1$?
   If not, what is $\widehat{\beta}_1^{(3)}$ and what does it mean?
2. What are the differences between $\widehat{\beta}_1^{(1)}$, $\widehat{\beta}_1^{(2)}$ and $\widehat{\beta}_1^{(3)}$?

---

I am very curious about $\widehat{\beta}_1^{(3)}$. But I was not able to find relevant materials for self-study.

Although, I think $\widehat{\beta}_1^{(3)}$ is a weighted least squares estimate with weight $[I_n−x_2 (x_2^\prime x_2 )^{−1} x_2^\prime ]$.
However, I don't know how to derive this [weighted least-squares estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares), what does the weight matrix mean, and when to use $\widehat{\beta}_1^{(2)}$ or $\widehat{\beta}_1^{(3)}$.

Thanks.